# CSS Header with multiple background images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a header having two background images, one being a white ribbon, and the other being my logo. I want something like:

[image]

I tried CSS3 and now I have this:

[image]

As you can see, the logo is clipped. Increasing the header size did not help me. I tried increasing the header size, aligning the `ul` in the center, but the ribbon showed as a white layer only. I cannot reduce the size of my logo to make it fit into the header, otherwise that would be too small.

**CODE**:

```
#header{
    background-image: url(../images/logo.png), url(../images/header_bg.png);
    background-size: auto, cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center center, top center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    font-size: 24px;
    //height: 100px;
    margin-left: 16%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:      border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/ayushkhemka/PGy3T/

Can't post more than 2 links or answer my own question until 8 hours :(

Comment: Why don't you put your logo as an image? This way you can also give it a link to your homepage.

Comment: JSfiddle/Codpen showing your HTML/CSS would be helpful.

Comment: @Kuzgun and add it as a `li`?

Comment: Using two background images isn't the best way to do this. Inside the header, absolute position your logo wherever you want.

Comment: Is your ribbon solid white?  Have you considered using CSS ribbons?  http://bloomwebdesign.net/2013/10/css-ribbon-tutorial/

Comment: yes, solid white, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the ribbon as the background image and apply the other image in the center as another element as part of the header using `position: absolute`.

Comment: works with some tweaks in the css of the image too to make it perfectly centered. Also required me to make `li:nth-of-type(5)` to give a `padding-left`

Answer (score 0):

This is your working code, please check this:

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(logo.png) , url(header_bg.png);
    background-size: auto, auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center center, center center;  
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 276px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:      border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

Comment: I have to adjust the margins of my `ul` to make it fit inside the header properly, which causes resolution issues. Besides, this seems like a make do solution, I was looking for a code which could make the **images resize according to the header** rather than **header resizing according to the images**

Comment: calling a logo image using img tag might be a solution.